# Integrate generated images into webkit browser in .NET

Tags: .net, webkit, webkit.net

I'd like to use the .NET port of WebKit (http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) to display generated HTML as well as generated images.

I can set the document html easily using the `DocumentText` property. How could I pass the images into the browser?

I've found a solution implementing a local web server but I wonder if there's a more direct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the images into data URIs and use those in the 'src' attributes of your image tags.